# UIBackgroundFetch and Remote notification relation

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

I want didReceivePushNotification to gets call when app receive the push notification in background. For that do I need to enable background fetch in background mode ? is there any relationship between Push Notification and background fetch of Background Mode capability.?